# Como abrir um alertDialog sem escurecer a tela?

Tags: android

Tenho este alertDialog:

```
private void createInfoWindow() {
    AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity);
    alert.setCancelable(true);
    alert.setView(R.layout.middle_window_adapter);
    alert.show();
}
```

Como faço para a tela por trás não escurecer?

Answer (score 1):

Você pode declarar o background dele como transparente

Por exemplo:

```
AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity);
    alert.setCancelable(true);
    getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
    alert.setView(R.layout.middle_window_adapter);
    alert.show();
```

Comment: Não funcionou. A tela por trás do alert, deve não esmaecer.